# как сделать чтобы при скролле колёсиком мыши листались все слайдеры сразу swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

вопрос по swiper.js 
как мне сделать чтобы при скролле колёсиком мыши листались все слайдеры на странице?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, нужно указать в параметр прокрутки мышью свойство eventsTarget и указать body 
Чтобы получилось так: 
mousewheel: {
eventsTarget: 'body',
},

Answer (score 0):

Нужен код. Какие у вас слайдеры. А вообще событие document.addEventListener('wheel',function(event){})б обычно при прокрутке выдается какая-то величина. Вот в зависимости от знака - или + перед ней, производите действия в слайдерах.